# How to use objective-zip replace or delete the file inside the zip file？

Tags: ios, replace

I can append file, but I need replace or delete file. Help, thank you.

Comment: `Unzip zip to folder.` `Fetch all files inside the folder.` `Remove/Replace file.` `Zip again.` You can use https://github.com/mattconnolly/ZipArchive

Comment: unzip zip is so slowly.

Comment: There is no other way around. Though you can see the ZipArchive class, and add your method, as they open zip and keep in memory.. Check for `addFileToZip` implementation.